# Pip index-url issue with nested dependencies

Tags: python, pip, offline, mirror

I currently have a pip mirror installed on an internal server (this is an offline network). The url to access it is http://pypi.python.org/simple. I have created a configuration file at ~/.pip/pip.conf with the following contents:

```
[global]
index-url = http://pypi.python.org/simple
trusted-host = pypi.python.org
```

I can successfully install packages that don't have nested dependencies, such as by performing `pip3 install requests`. I get the output of it installing requests, idna, chardet, certifi, and urllib3 successfully. However, when I need to install something from pip that has nested dependencies, such as via `pip3 install driller`, I get the following output:

```
Collecting driller
  Downloading driller-1.0.tar.gz
Collecting angr (from driller)
  Downloading angr-8.19.2.4.tar.gz (758kB)
  100% |                          | 768kB 75.7MB/s
  Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
  Download error on https://pypi.python.org/simple/pyvex/: [Errno 111] Connection refused -- Some packages may not be found!
  ...
```

It's weird to me that the error occurs as a result of attempting to reach https://pypi.python.org/simple as opposed to my local mirror that I specified via index-url at http://pypi.python.org. Additionally, if I perform `pip3 install pyvex` it installs just fine. Am I missing how to propagate my index-url/trusted host through the pip install command when there are nested dependencies?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does Pip disregard configured repository with nested dependencies?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59932377/why-does-pip-disregard-configured-repository-with-nested-dependencies)

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same question and got the answer in this thread on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59932377/why-does-pip-disregard-configured-repository-with-nested-dependencies).

### Here is the solution

Find the Python directories on your system and add the following two lines to the `distutils.cfg` in the folder `distutils`. If the config file does not exist yet, create it.

```
[easy_install]
index_url = blablabla
```